# Is there actually current flow around an atom?

Tags: electrons

The classical model of the moment of a loop of current, which is $\mu = I A$, where A is the loop area. I'm in an introductory E&M course where the moment of an atom is modeled using this simple formula, if we represent the electron as a point charge.

This makes sense for me for (very) large orbits due to the correspondence principle. However, in QM we represent the moment from an electron in this situation using its orbital angular momentum where

$$\mu = g \mu_B \frac{L}{\hbar}$$

I know that L = $r \times p$. Both of these operators (p & v) specify an action on the rotation group of our Hilbert space, and the **r** operator is analogous to the radius of an orbiting charge in classical mechanics. But there is also spin angular momentum, which we can't define using a position operator. My question is that since both of these can contribute to the electron's magnetic moment, do quantum mechanical effects always create a definable "current" around the electron in the classical sense (i.e. charge per unit time), as they would in the limit of large quantum numbers? Or is the "rotating point charge" analogy completely inaccurate? (Or somewhere in between?)

Comment: I think the question of how we define current quantum mechanically is a good one (and I'm guessing it'll likely lead you to quantum electrodynamics), but I also think the rotating point charge analogy is ultimately totally inaccurate—if I remember correctly, part of the motivation for quantum mechanics was that any charge orbiting an atom would, by virtue of the acceleration required for orbit, radiate away all of its energy and spiral into the nucleus. That said, I don't know to what degree you can simply say "the electron magically doesn't do that" and get away with it in the equations...

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.14580).